# SSIS data validation

Tags: json, sql-server-2008, ssis, msbi

I have a json file that comes with around 125 columns and I need to load it to a DB Table.I'm using SSIS package and after dumping all the JSON file contents to a DB DUMP Table,I need to validate the data and load only the data that is valid to the MASTER Table and Send the rest to a failure table.The failure Table has 250 columns with ERROR for each column.If the first column fails validation,I need to write the error message to the corresponding error column and continue with the validation of second column...Is there some utility IN SSIS that helps in achieving the requirement.

I've tried using Conditional Split but appears like it doesn't fit the bill..
 Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: I'd handle it with a stored proc that you call from an Execute SQL task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Alleman's suggestion of getting this done via stored procedure. In terms of implementation there are various ways with which you can go about. I am listing one way here

In the database you can create some 10 stored procedures as follows

- dbo.usp_ValidateData_Columns1_To_Columns25
- dbo.usp_ValidateData_Columns26_To_Columns50
- ....
- ....
- dbo.usp_ValidateData_Columns226_To_Columns250

In each of this procedures you can have the validate your data in bulk across columns. If validation fails you can insert into the respective error columns.

Once you have this in place you can then call all the above procedures in parallel as part of your SSIS Package.

Post that you would need one more DFT, to pick all those records which are good to be transferred to MASTER.

Basically you are modularizing the whole setup.